# How nested td value can render new row?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[
{

```
    "course": "Bachelor of Computer Science",
    "level": "Bachelor's Degree",
    "provider": [
        {
            "school": "Harvard University",
            "duration": "156"
        },
        {
            "school": "Yales University",
            "duration": "156"
        },
        {
            "school": "BYU-Provo",
            "duration": "208"
        }
       
    ]
}
```

]

I am fetching data from an API and it gives me something like the above code. I want to create a table. I did something like this

```
data .map((item) => {
     return `
   <tr class="grid-row">
   <td>${item.course}</td>
   <td>${item.level}</td>
    ${provider(item.provider)}  // Loops through the provider array 
</tr>
```

and  I get something like this

| Course | Level | Provider |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Science | BSC. | Harvard University Yales University BYU-PROVO |

How to create a new row with a different provider but the same course and level? So that it would create something like this

| Course | Level | Provider |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Science | BSC. | Harvard University |
| Science | BSC. | Yales University |
| Science | BSC. | BYU-Provo |
|  |  |  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get data from API via $.get() function and use append method to add rows to tbody tag.
For example;
index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Course</th>
                <th>Level</th>
                <th>Provider</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```js
function createTable(data){
    const {course, level, provider} = data;
    const tableBody = $('tbody');
    for (let i; i<provider.length; i++){
        const school = provider[i].school;
        tableBody.append(`
            <tr>
                <th>${course}</th>
                <td>${level}</td>
                <td>${school}</td>
            </tr>
        `)
    }
}

$.get('<url>', createTable);
```

Comment: {course, level, provider} = data   if I console.log (course) it says undefined. I am getting the data though.

Comment: I realise your main data is array, right now. Your should edit code section of your question. So you need get object from array by index. Try something like that const {course, level, provider} = data[0];

Comment: I did [{course,level,provider}] = data and it worked. Thanks for your help. It did work. 